# systemd wait for Env variable from external to trigger service start

Tags: debian, systemd, systemctl, cloud-init

I have a VM which I'm controlling the boot up process via `systemd` and `cloud-init`.
For `cloud-init` I have a script that performs initialization as follows:

```
runcmd:
- /etc/systemd/system/init.sh
```

`/etc/systemd/system/init.sh` contents:

```
  systemctl start service-1
  systemctl start service-2
  systemctl start service-3
  systemctl start service-4
  systemctl start service-5
```

The VM operates in 2 modes:

a) Sequential:
All the services use: `EnvironmentFile=/tmp/ENV` file to read ENV variables and operate in `simple` or `oneshot` Type.

b) Waiting mode:

Service 1 to 3 start, but 4-5 need to wait an external signal to start. This signal will update an ENV variable in `/tmp/ENV`
Service 4 and 5 have to wait as they require this ENV variable value.
I can easily introduce a new service that receive notification and then continue sequence.

```
systemctl start service-1
systemctl start service-2
systemctl start service-3
systemctl start service-handle-notification
systemctl start service-4
systemctl start service-5
```

But looking to see if there is a recommended pattern to make `service-4` and `service-5` be on standby and then start upon notification. Read about `Type=notify` but that just blocks a service and control does not execute next service.

Question:

`systemctl start service-handle-notification` I can set mode 'forking' or any mode to run in background.

How can I have bot service 4-5 to be wait while a signal is dispatched from `service-handle-notification`

Is there a better pattern with systemd (Example: Before/After)

Answer (score 2):

First, don't start multiple services like this:

```
systemctl start service-1
systemctl start service-2
systemctl start service-3
systemctl start service-4
systemctl start service-5
systemctl start service-handle-notification
```

Start them like this:

```
systemctl start \
  service-1 \
  service-2 \
  service-3 \
  service-4 \
  service-5 \
  service-handle-notification
```

If you have before/after ordering on your services, it's only relevant if they are started at the same time.

With that change in place, make `service-handle-notification.service` a `Type=oneshot` service:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=...
```

And then make `service-4` and `service-5` depend on that service:

```
[Unit]
Requires=service-handle-notification.service
After=service-handle-notification.service
```

With this configuration, `service-4` and `service-5` won't start until *after* `service-handle-notification` completes.